# Figuring out the fixed characters in (for example) a ISBN number

Tags: standard-deviation, goodness-of-fit

I'm trying to remove positions that contain fixed values from strings of random data. An example is removing the string "ISBN" from a book isbn code without prior knowledge of that being a fixed string or where in the string it occurs, but with the knowledge that it won't move around. A complication is that they don't have to be be perfectly fixed, just mostly.

Here is the current implementation:

"

I am given a list of strings

```
{"0113","0124",0132","0242"};
```

My goal is to identify which positions are mostly the same.

I take the proportions of each character in each position:

```
              "0"   "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"
position 0 : { 1,    0,     0      0      0   }  sd: 0.43...
position 1 : { 0,    0.75,  0.25,  0,     0   }  sd: 0.31...
position 2 : { 0,    0.25,  0.25,  0.25,  0.25}  sd: 0
position 3 : { 0,    0,     0.5,   0.25,  0.25}  sd: 0.18...
```

I then calculate the variance of these position data sets. This seems to work out as a sort of goodness of fit tests against the uniform distribution (fitted perfectly by position 2). I can then specify some threshold at which everything above is (mostly) fixed value.

"

This seems wrong. If I change the number of available characters, say by adding "5", this changes the values. It actually decreases the sd, so that I'm less sure {1,0,0,0,0,0} is a fixed string than {1,0}, which seems the opposite of correct.

Is this close to something that would work. If not, what statistical techniques can I base
an actually assessment of which positions in the my strings vary and which do not?

Incidentally, I realise that maybe just setting a threshold on the proportion is a way to go, but I suspect there is something more robust and I would like to know what the person who wrote that implementation was actually trying to achieve.

edit: It would be less variable if I multiplied the proportions by the size of the character set, eg  `position 0 : { 5,    0,     0      0      0   }`, but that also seems not correct.